# Custom Membership - Error in Web Site Administration Tool (Type is not resolved for member'')

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-membership, custom-membershipprovider, website-admin-tool

I had to customize the class `MembershipProvider` for the user validation is done by email.

But when you open the Asp.net Web Site Administration Tool, the "Security" tab the following error:

> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused
>   by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient
>   permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not
>   being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where
>   you can choose a new data store.
>
> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Type is not
>   resolved for member
>   'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException,EntityFramework,
>   Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

*Because the code is great and not to pollute the topic, I put on github.*

**Code:**

https://gist.github.com/1146084

Comment: I did not see your connection string named "Data" - can you post it as well? Also post the rest of your web.config where it registers the different dlls such as EF.

Comment: I updated the file.
Look again.

Answer (score 0):

While I am still new to MVC 3 and EF 4.1, try adding a line in your web.config for EntityFramework assembly. It seems like I had this problem as well with my setup. I can't remember the exact line, but it's something like (I will look it up when I get home):

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```